# AttributeError: [Pandas] 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, pandas

Following the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) I am trying to take the mode of the columns of a pandas dataframe, but I get an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mode'`. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "B"], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})


df.mode()
```

And here is the traceback:

```
    df.mode()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2088, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

How do I take the mode of a column?

Comment: you need pandas 0.13.0 at least (0.13.1 coming soon)

Comment: "I was there when they added the ability to take the mode. That's right, the mode!" Thanks, updated the package and it works perfectly.